# Display n most frequent used commands Linux

Tags: zsh

A command in linux to list the top *N* most frequent commands used in your *zsh*.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Linux, but why did you tag this bash **and** zsh? If you need the problem solved for both shells, ask two questions - one for bash, and one for zsh.

Comment: @user1934428 I use both bash and zsh, don't see why I can't ask about both

Comment: You might want to try in [unix.se]. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @YuriAps: The reason why asking two problems in one question is following: Say I know only the answer to the first problem (and post it), and someone else knows only the answer to the second problem (and posts it), what are you going to do? You are supposed to accept the answer which solves your problem, but Stackoverflow allows you to accept only one answer. You can't accept both. Therefore the policiy in Stackoverflow is "one problem - one question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `zsh`

```
fc -ln 0 | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -<X>
```

`fc -ln 0` - show the history
`awk` - prints only the command without the arguments
`sort` - for using the next pipe
`uniq -c` - count uniques commands
`sort -rn` - sort by number in reverse
`head -<X>` - list the top X

similar to `bash`

```
history | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn| head -<X>
```

Special thanks to @ericbn